# How I can fix remote origin problems in Git

Tags: git

Please I have a problem with Git :(

I created new repository in github and copied the links.

When I try to `git remote add origin link` , I receive error that origin already exist and then with this command  : `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/your/repository`

After push, in github I have found another files from the last repository with the new file I have push it.

---

```
Khouloud Ben Salah@Khouloud MINGW64 ~/PycharmProjects/pythonProject (origin|REVERTING)
$ git push origin main
error: src refspec main does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Abdelhakim-Aouay/exercices_python.git'
```

Comment: if you have used `git clone`, it sets the origin. did you use cloning?

Comment: I suspect that your problem is more basic than you think: I think you have created an *unrelated* repository on your laptop. But it's not completely clear. You might want to add the output from `git status` and from `git remote -v`. Your prompt shows that you are in the middle of an unfinished `git revert` operation; you'll need to complete that, or terminate it. You have no branch named `main` in your laptop repository.

Comment: ylmaz Durmaz << Yes I have use git clone

Comment: torek<< my proble is I want to add new project in new reposotiry. After git init,git add, git commit,  git remote add origin (Url of neww repositiry), git branch-M main, and git push origin main. Github inform me that origin already exist and if I push -f. in new reposiry i have the new file and the file of the last repositiry

Answer (score -2):

remote command

get Remote

`git remote`

delete remote

`git remote remove origin`

add remote

`git remote add origin url`

first add you can add and commit and push origin